# Passing the name of spool file to sqlplus from a shell script

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a unix program, in which I need to connect to the SQL DB and fetch the data and store it into a file.

Currently I am using the following command:

```
output1=`sqlplus -s username@SID/password <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING ON ECHO OFF;
SPOOL EMP_NAMES.txt
select emp_name from employee order by emp_name;
Spool off;
```

This is working fine. But my requirement was that I want to pass the value of spool file such that everytime a new Spool file would be generated.

I basically want to append the date at the end of the file name like:

```
date=`date +'%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S:%2N'`
output1=`sqlplus -s username@SID/password <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING ON ECHO OFF;
SPOOL EMP_NAMES_$date.txt
```

Kindly let me know as to how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your `sqlplus` with a heredoc, you can do this easily:

```
spool_file=: ... your date logic here ...
sql_ouput=: ... path for sqlplus output & errors ...
sqlplus -s username@SID/password << EOF &> "$sql_output"
  SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING ON ECHO OFF;
  spool $spool_file
  # SQL statements
  spool off
EOF
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  : ... error handling ...
fi
```

- It's better to capture stdout/stderr of `sqlplus` into a file rather than a shell variable.
- I think it is possible to hide the password by removing it from the command line and adding it as the first line of heredoc (this will prevent password from showing in `ps`)

Take a look at this related post: [Connect to sqlplus in a shell script and run SQL scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277983/connect-to-sqlplus-in-shell-script-and-run-a-sql-script-file)

Comment: Thanks @codeforester for super quick response!!!
Ive tried the steps suggested but still getting the error.
 spoolFile="SPOOL_FILE_"$date".txt"
output1=`sqlplus -s username@SID/pwd <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING ON ECHO OFF COLSEP |;
SPOOL $spoolFile
     Query...
SPOOL OFF;

Kindly let me know if there is any step that I've missed out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "EOF" at the very beginning of the line and there are no other characters on that line?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Its at the end of the line like --
output1=`sqlplus -s username@SID/pwd <<EOF



Error is like --
./Shell.sh: line 351: SPOOL_FILE.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: Thank you @codeforester !!! It worked. I just re-wrote the code in the similar way mentioned by you and it worked. Thanks a lot !!!