# How to startup automatically Oracle 19C using bash scripting and SQL PLUS?

Tags: bash, oracle, oracle19c

I've tried to create a bash script for connecting to my *Oracle 19C* database using *sqlplus*, I added the following code (which works also) :

```
#! /bin/sh.
connectsqlplus(){
    sqlplus "'"sys/mypassword as sysdba"'" 
EOF 
}
connectsqlplus
```

The main problem is that I want to use this bash script to start the database, what I've created seems to only let me open the *sqlplus* terminal, I just want to add the *`SQL> startup`* so that the database starts but I'm not really sure how to add this command in the SQL terminal by using bash scripting.

Any help would be much appreciated ! Thank you .

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/startup.htm#ADMQS124

Comment: From bash script I asked, not from the SQLPLUS command line which opens after I enter the code and execute the script from above.

Comment: Then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277983/connect-to-sqlplus-in-a-shell-script-and-run-sql-scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#start_oracle_db.sh
ORACLE_SID=nameofyourdatabaseasrecordedinoratabfile
ORAENV_ASK=NO
source oraenv
sqlplus << EOF
connect / as sysdba
startup
exit
EOF
```

Comment: Appreciate it "